# Date regex produce false output

Tags: python

I need to find the files whose pattern match to the date format in Python. Could someone please help me on this. I have a regex but it's not working as required.

```
date = '2012-01-15'

match = re.findall(r'^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$', date)
print match
```

Output:

```
[('20', '01','15')]
```

Comment: Can you explain what "not working as required" means? Also, Python 2.2.1 was released on April 10, 2002. That's *really* old.

Comment: I know tht's really old cant help:( But i need regex as date format as 20120323(yyyymmdd). I need to compare wether a file name is in yyyymmdd format. Can u help

Comment: Isn't this what your code does?

Comment: no it dont do tht. I am veryy new to python, no idea why isnt it working

Comment: Some one can help me in the above question, its quite urgent.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just missed a pair of parenthesis around the complete year match and you probably want to suppress the century match with `?:`:

```
match = re.findall(r'^((?:19|20)\d\d)[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$', date)
#                     ^ ^^          ^
```

this gives `[('2012', '01', '15')]` on your example